# Getting an exception when trying to convert JSON with an empty property name to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I've got a service that takes various file formats from my clients and converts them to XML to be processed by an internal processing engine.  For JSON I'm using Json.Net's *JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode* to convert the JSON to XML.  Today I've run into an issue where a client is sending JSON that contains a property with an empty name, which apparently is a valid scenario.  When I try to convert to XML I get the exception below.  What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to tell the XmlNodeConverter that I want it to either skip or give a default name to an element when this happens.  Is that possible?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

**Sample Unit Test:**

```
[Test]
public void TestParseEmptyName( )
{
    string json = @"
    {
        ""Row"":{
            """":123
        }
    }";

    XmlDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode( json );
}
```

**The exception I'm getting is:**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=XmlNodeConverter cannot convert JSON with an empty property name to XML. Path 'Row.', line 1, position 14.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
  StackTrace:
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.CreateElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String elementName, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String elementPrefix, Dictionary`2 attributeNameValues)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName, Boolean writeArrayAttribute)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value)
   at BMS.Common.Test.Text.JSONParserFixture.TestParseEmptyName() in C:\SVNRepository\BMSProducts\LoanTradeDesk\trunk\Source Code\Common\BMS.Common.Test\Text\JSONParserFixture.cs:line 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlNodeConverter` does not seem to provide any public options to change how it handles empty JSON property names.  I would have suggested subclassing the converter, but most of its internal methods are private, so that pretty much kills that idea.

It looks like your best option is to pre-process the JSON to replace the empty property names with some other value.  You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to do this, then send the corrected JSON to `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode` as you were before.  I would create a small helper class like this:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static XmlDocument ConvertToXml(string json)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
        // Change "blank" to whatever you want the replacement name to be.
        ReplaceEmptyPropertyNames(token, "blank");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(token.ToString());
    }

    public static void ReplaceEmptyPropertyNames(JToken token, string replaceWithName)
    {
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>().ToList())
            {
                if (prop.Name == string.Empty)
                {
                    prop.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty(replaceWithName, prop.Value));
                    prop.Remove();
                }
                ReplaceEmptyPropertyNames(prop.Value, replaceWithName);
            }
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in token.Children())
            {
                ReplaceEmptyPropertyNames(child, replaceWithName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, just replace `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode()` with  `JsonHelper.ConvertToXml()`:

```
[Test]
public void TestParseEmptyName( )
{
    string json = @"
    {
        ""Row"":{
            """":123
        }
    }";

    XmlDocument xdoc = JsonHelper.ConvertToXml( json );
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahvytn